# Where does Vetur get its rules from?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, vuejs3, vetur

I'm trying to work out where Vetur gets all its rules from. I created a minimal Vue 3 project with TS via the CLI without linting. The package file looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "core-js": "^3.6.5",
  "vue": "^3.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
  "typescript": "~4.1.5"
}
```

The tsconfig file contains:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "esnext",
  "module": "esnext",
  "strict": true,
  ...
}
```

In a setup file I add:

```
setup() {
  const test;

  return {
    test,
  };
},
```

And I get the errors:

> 'const' declarations must be initialized.Vetur(1155)

> Variable 'test' implicitly has an 'any' type.Vetur(7005)

Which is fine, I want these errors to be displayed I would just like to know where they come from? Is there a rule list somewhere? Can I look up rule 1155? Is it possible to override these rules?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like these are TypeScript errors - they have the same numbers in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.3.5/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json, for example. Not sure how Vetur gets them, however.

Comment: Ah yes thankyou - this is what I was looking for! I'm happy to accept this as the answer because finding this list of rules was my main goal